# Attaching resources in Vue component tests

Tags: vue.js, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I'm running component tests on my Vue project, have followed the documentation [Getting Started with Cypress Component Testing (Vue 2/3)](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/getting-start-with-cypress-component-testing-vue-2-3/).

```js
import { mount } from '@cypress/vue'
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld', () => {
  it('renders a message', () => {
    const msg = 'Hello Cypress Component Testing!'
    mount(HelloWorld, {
      propsData: {
        msg
      }
    })

    cy.get('h1').should('have.text', msg)
  })
})
```

How do I include resources that are normally loaded to `index.html`, as there is no base page in component tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your resource link on `document` and attach your component to a child element of the same document, for example

```js
const div = document.createElement('div')
div.id = 'root'
document.body.appendChild(div)

const linkElem = document.createElement('link');
linkElem.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
linkElem.setAttribute('href', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/6.7.96/css/materialdesignicons.min.css');
document.head.appendChild(linkElem)

mount(HelloWorld, {
  propsData: {
    msg
  },
  attachTo: '#root'
})
```